# Why am I getting a ValueError in XGBoost when predicting hotel room prices?

Tags: python, xgboost

Hi I was building a Machine learning model where it is predict the prices of hotel room based on previous data. I tried to use XGBoost but I came across this error message.

ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels: [0.0, 0.31, 0.39, 0.46, 0.91, 1.09, 1.16, 1.22, 1.24, 1.34, 1.39, 1.41, 1.46, 1.59, 1.79, 1.81

```
            This is my XGBoost code  `
            X = dataset1.loc\[:, 'date_time'\]
            y = dataset1.loc\[:, 'price_usd'\]

            X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
            X_train.shape, X_valid.shape, y_train.shape, y_valid.shape
            xgboost.XGBClassifier().get_params()
            model_xgboost = xgboost.XGBClassifier(learning_rate=0.1,
            max_depth=5,
            n_estimators=5000,
            subsample=0.5,
            colsample_bytree=0.5,
            eval_metric='auc',
            verbosity=1)

            eval_set = \[(X_valid, y_valid)\]

            model_xgboost.fit(X_train,
            y_train,
            early_stopping_rounds=10,
            eval_set=eval_set,
            verbose=True)



            The dataset looks like this

            price_usd   date_time   prop_id srch_adults_count
            0   104.77  2013-04-04 08:32:15 893 4.0
            1   170.74  2013-04-04 08:32:15 10404   4.0
            2   179.80  2013-04-04 08:32:15 21315   4.0
            3   602.77  2013-04-04 08:32:15 27348   4.0
            4   143.58  2013-04-04 08:32:15 29604   4.0
```

For almost 9000 rows

I am unsure why I am having this error message

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please post the complete error traceback message.